# Is there a way to retrieve the time data the Contact passed the Activity in Journey Builder via API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, activityhistory

Is there a way to retrieve the time data the Contact passed the Activity in Journey Builder via API?
please check the image.the highlighted part is the data I hope to retrieve

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can retrieve it with this undocumented REST endpoint:

```
POST /interaction/v1/interactions/journeyhistory/search?$pageSize=500&$page=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: YOURTENANTHERE.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "contactKeys": [
          "test@example.com"
        , "test2@example.com"
    ],
    "definitionIds": [],
    "activityTypes": [],
    "start": "2023-01-01T06:00:00.000Z",
    "end": null,
    "statuses": []
}
```

Results:

```javascript
{
    "count": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 500,
    "links": {},
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "2222222",
            "longId": 2222222,
            "mid": 1111111,
            "eventId": "2400cea6-4cd4-42f9-a8a8-d60e48f8d5ed",
            "definitionId": "a185ec86-b6b4-4077-900e-8269a6274623",
            "definitionName": "ASpriggs-JB-API-Test",
            "eventName": "Trigger_Test",
            "contactKey": "test@example.com",
            "epochTimeInMilliseconds": 1677003237721,
            "transactionTime": "2023-02-21T18:13:57.721Z",
            "status": "ContactAttempted",
            "clientStatus": "Success",
            "createdDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "eid": 1111111,
            "startDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "endDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "sourceType": 0,
            "_score": 0.0,
            "messageSource": 3
        }
    ]
 }
```